# Log Elasticsearch requests/queries to stdout for a docker instance using docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, docker-compose

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch locally (for development purposes) using the normal docker container found on dockerhub.

When I run the instance locally, I'm hoping to see all queries get dumped to stdout/console so I can easily see what queries my elastic-SDK client creates/composes/executes.

I've seen some comments around the place that suggest it could be done by customising various settings, like:

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 0s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 0s
index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 0s
```

but I'm not sure how to do this via docker-compose.

I tried the following but ES crashed on startup:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: my-elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:  
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.deb=0s
      - index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug=0s
      - index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug=0s
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding another answer for Version equal or greater than 5.X,

1. These are the current major versions being used.
2. Setting asked in question are deprecated from the Elasticsearch 5.X and using them in `elasticsearch.yml` throws below error:

> elasticsearch    | {"type": "server", "timestamp":
>   "2020-04-04T10:18:57,720Z", "level": "WARN", "component":
>   "o.e.c.s.SettingsModule", "cluster.name": "ami-es", "node.name":
>   "e35893907d50", "message":
>   "\n*************************************************************************************\nFound index level settings on node level configuration.\n\nSince
>   elasticsearch 5.x index level settings can NOT be set on the nodes
>   \nconfiguration like the elasticsearch.yaml, in system properties or
>   command line \narguments.In order to upgrade all indices the settings
>   must be updated via the \n/${index}/_settings API. Unless all settings
>   are dynamic all indices must be closed \nin order to apply the
>   upgradeIndices created in the future should use index templates \nto
>   set default values. \n\nPlease ensure all required values are updated
>   on all indices by executing: \n\ncurl -XPUT
>   'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true' -d '{\n 
>   \"index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug\" : \"0ms\",\n 
>   \"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug\" : \"0ms\",\n 
>   \"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug\" :
>   \"0ms\"\n}'\n*************************************************************************************\n" }

**Basically to solve it, instead of mentioning them in `elasticsearch.yml`, simply hit below API and it would work.**

PUT http://{{hostname}}:{{es-port}}/{{index-name}}/_settings

```
{
    "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.warn": "0s",
    "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.info": "0s",
    "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug": "0s",
    "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.trace": "0s",
    "index.indexing.slowlog.level": "info",
    "index.indexing.slowlog.source": "1000"
}
```

Comment: So I have to use the API to turn the settings on instead of using some env-var or some boot setting?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, yes as based on your elastic version in docker-compose, you need to turn these settings and good news are these are dynamic so you can immediately verify it.

Answer (score 1):

### For Elasticsearch versions lower than 5.X (these are index specific settings and deprecated from ES versions 5.X)

### Elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: "my-es-cluster" 
network.host: 0.0.0.0
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 0ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 0ms
index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 0ms
```

### Docker-compose.yml content

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  #Elasticsearch Docker Images: https://www.docker.elastic.co/
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
```

Edit: As per OPs comments,

1. You can keep the elasticsearch.yml anywhere in localhost, but need to properly refer under volume section, best is to keep it beside the docker-compose file, and then use ./ which means current folder in *nix based systems.
2. Yes, need to create the docker-compose.yml with the content, given here and change the volume section, so that `elasticsearch.yml` file present in your local will be used to create the Elasticsearch docker with same settings and configs mentioned in localhost's config file.
3. Docker for elasticsearch in this compose file `*nix` hence no need to change the volume section after the `:` section in volume, but before that it's your localhost file system, so change it accordingly.

Let me know if you face any issues and would be happy to help further.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the awesome reply. So let me get this right, first I need to 1) create an `elasticsearch.yml` file a place it somewhere on my localhost. 2) change the `docker-compose.yml` file to the above. 3) change the `volume` section so ES uses my localhost file (outside of the container instance) as it's config.

Side note: I'm on a windows pc, so the volume will have to be different, I guess.

Comment: Oh - sorry .. I forgot to also ask ... can you please post a very quick sample of the `elasticsearch.yml` file which I should create, also? It is _literally_ an empty file with those three settings in it?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, please give me sometime and I would provide this

Comment: @Pure.Krome, As promised I provided my answer :), sorry for the delay but got busy with the work and finally got some time during the weekend only to go through it and it involved reproducing issue, debugging etc